# installing c compiler on an offline machine

Tags: offline, compiler

i am new to ubuntu. i have been programming physics and rendering logic for pc games in c, c++ and opengl on windows os for years. i cannot use windows any longer and i am trying linux out. i want to continue development using linux. i am learning on ubuntu studio (newest release) but my dev work pcs are completely offline machines. always. i need to install a c compiler and linker to build from sources but i am having trouble finding an offline installer or package for gcc or any other for that matter. i cannot use 'software center' or 'sudo apt get ...' because it is an offline only machine. i have to get some kind of package or offline installer, and transfer it between machines via usb-stick to install on my offline work-station. i came to ubuntu to be free from windows os and online enforced design paradigm, but all advice i find is to use 'sudo apt get ...'. ubuntu seems to be more internet dependant than windows by far. i am here to stay and learn though.
does anyone know of any install solutions. if not, would it be possible to create a basic c99 compiler from scratch using terminal commands? because then i could compile another, official c or c++ compiler and make tools to resume work officially. thank you for your time. i appreciate you all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: You can always set your workstation up and tune up that to your need (making ready for your working condition) and then can go completely offline afterwards or just could setup the compiler that way.

Comment: thank you for the quick replies. i cannot put that work-station pc online for set up and then take it offline after. it is an offline only work-station. the ules are not entirely up to me. i work with a team. the solutions in the 'possible duplicate' involve going online on that machine. here is what i need to do: use one of the pcs at work that are allowed to be online (they are all windows 7 64bit) to download source files.

Comment: transfer source files to offline machine. build source files... but i need a c compiler and linker to build. my offline ubuntu studio machine does not have one. i need to build somehow.

Comment: if i can build from source i will be good from there i think. i just need a c compiler and linker i can transfer to my offline machine. does anybody know how i can get an offline c linker/compiler so i can even build make in the first place to buildfrom sources that i can easily transfer over? thank you for your time.

Comment: i apologize if i come across as rude or dispolotic. i do not want to give that impression. there has to be a way.

Comment: i will try my best to make an offline repository an get back to everyone.